# Django Max & Min pricse filter from models

Tags: python, django

I created an DJANGO models in my "models.py" contains "Item_Frash_pricse" field in it

```
class Item(models.Model):
      item_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
      item_category = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      item_subCategory = models.CharField(max_length=30)
      item_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='') 
      item_titile = models.CharField(max_length=30) 
      item_FrashPricse = models.FloatField(max_length=30)
```

the **PROBLEM** is that i want to fetch all the query set where Item_Frash_pricse <= max_amount andItem_Frash_pricse >= min amount are

in my "views.py"

```
def ByPricse(request,filter_by):
    max_amount = request.GET.get('Maxamount',None)
    min_amount = request.GET.get('Minamount',None)
    **filter_item = Item.objects.filter(Item_Frash_pricse <= max_amount and vise versa ????**)
    return HttpResponse('Ok')
```

But this **filter_item = Item.objects.filter(Item_Frash_pricse <= max_amount** is wrong syantax cant do >= opration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use filter as follows

```
filter_item = Item.objects.filter(item_FrashPricse__lte=max_amount).filter(
                    item_FrashPricse__gte=min_amount)
```

or we can use `Q` to filter

```
from django.db.models import Q

filter_item  = Item.objects.filter(Q(item_FrashPricse__lte=max_amount)&
                    Q(item_FrashPricse__gte=min_amount))
```

Comment: Thats Work Fine Thank u